Smooth map $F$ has rank $r$ at a point implies $F$ has constant rank in some neighborhood of that point?
Suppose $M,N$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary, $p\in M$ and $F:M\to N$ is a smooth map. Then, is the following true?
Claim: $F$ has rank $r$ at $p$ (ie, by definition, $\dim(\text{Im}(dF_p))=r$) $\implies$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ st $F|_U$ is a constant rank map of rank $r$.
(I know that this works when $r=\dim(M):=m$ (ie $F$ is a smooth immersion) or $r=\dim(N):=n$ (ie $F$ is a smooth submersion), see Lee Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Proposition 4.1 for example).
Here is my attempt at proving the claim.
Choose any smooth co-ordinates $(U,\varphi)$ for $M$ near $p$ and $(V,\psi)$ for $N$ near $F(p)$ st $F(U)\subseteq V$. The Jacobian of $F$ at $p$ in this co-ordinate bases is the matrix representation of its co-ordinate representation $\hat{F}:=\psi F\varphi^{-1}$ at $\hat{p}:=\varphi(p)$. Hence, the matrix $d\hat{F}_{\hat{p}}$ has rank $r$ ie there is a $r\times r$-sub-matrix of $d\hat{F}_{\hat{p}}$ that is invertible.
Now consider the map,
$$\kappa:U\to \varphi(U)\to M_{n\times m}(\mathbb R)\to \mathbb R^k,$$
$$x\mapsto \hat{x}\mapsto d\hat{F}_{\hat{x}}\mapsto (\det(J^n(\hat{x}))),$$
where $k$ is the number of $r\times r$-submatrices of a $n\times m$-matrix. By $(\det(J^n(\hat{x})))$ I mean the tuple containing the determinant of each of the $k$-many $r\times r$-submatrices $J^n(\hat{x})$ of $d\hat{F}_{\hat{x}}$.
$\kappa$ is continuous (I hope)(I know that $\varphi$ is continuous, the map $\hat{x}\mapsto d\hat{F}_{\hat{x}}$ is continuous since $\hat{F}$ is smooth, taking determinant is smooth, taking the minors is some kind of projection and is hence continuous, but the rest I am not sure) map that is non-zero at $p$, hence there is a neighbourhood $U'$ of $p$ where $\kappa$ is non-zero. That is $\dim(d\hat{F}_{\hat{x}})=r$ for all $x\in U'$ ie $F|_{U'}$ is a constant rank map of rank $r$.
Any suggestions, proof improvements or counter-examples will be really helpful :))

Counterexample: $x \in \Bbb R \to x^2 \in \Bbb R$, around $0$. What is true is that in a small enough neighbourhood, the rank can only increase (it is a similar argument than your attempt). This implies that if $p_0$ is such that $\mathrm{rank} d_{p_0}F = \max_{p \in M} \mathrm{rank} d_pF$, then $F$ has constant ran around $p_0$.

The statement you're trying to prove is false. In fact, if it were true, then observe that if $M$ is connected your statement implies that $F$ has constant rank: The set of points at which $\operatorname{rank} F = r$ would be open for a given $r$ which gives you a decomposition of $M$ in disjoint open sets if $\operatorname{rank} F$ attains more than one value.
But there are obviously maps of non-constant rank on connected manifolds, for instance $f(x) = x^2$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself.

+1. In addition, and paraphrasing my comment above:
What is true is that in a small enough neighbourhood, the rank can only increase (it is a similar argument than OP's attempt). This implies that if $p_0$ is such that $\mathrm{rank}(d_{p_0}F)= \max_{p\in M} \mathrm{rank}(d_pF)$, then $F$ has constant rank around $p_0$.

Thanks. But is it possible to help me see where exactly my proof fails?

@frelg That there is a neighborhood of $p$ on which $\kappa$ is non-zero does not imply that $\dim d \tilde{F}_{\tilde{x}}$ is constant there, only that it does not decrease, since if it increases there will still be invertible $r \times r$ minors. Your proof can thus only show Didier's statement above.

Makes sense, thanks :))
